# connecting multiple web applications through SSO with the wso2 IS

Tags: service, wso2, provider

Following excellent article talks about SSO connection between one web application to wso2 IS through SAML2.0. 
http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server

My requirement is to connect multiple web applications through SSO with the wso2 IS. Can anyone give me some light on this how can I do that?
In another words if I login to any one of those webapp I can navigate to other webapps by clicking on the links available on the first webapp without relogin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is possible with WSO2 IS..You can refer [this](http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/08/saml20-sso-with-wso2-identity-server.html) for more information where you can find IS as the IDP for all the webapps...